# Duplicate network adapter after connection lost

Tags: networking, connection, adsl, adapter

Here's my problem... I'm running Windows XP SP2 with an ADSL connection. My modem is a Speedtouch 330. Sometimes the connection goes down and after reconnecting it I run ipconfig and the output looks something like this:

Windows IP Configuration

PPP adapter Speedtouch Connection:

```
    **Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :**
    **IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0**
    **Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255**
    **Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0**


    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 85.242.57.19
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 85.242.57.19
```

When I get this scenario I always have to restart because I can't browse... It's like all the traffic goes into that ghost connection...

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried running the PPPoE connection on the modem instead of the workstation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a brute force approach you could restart the network services service by doing start run services.msc then finding the network services service right clicking and doing restart. If this works you could create a batch file to do it.

Comment: Hmmm... good point... I will try next time it happens.